# Distinguish iPhone 3G from iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to distinguish an iPhone 3G from an iPhone 3G S using any of the properties of [UIDevice currentDevice]?

Comment: I don't know, and I wouldn't want to anyway. If you want to check for functionality, check for functionality instead of checking versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to check is to use `sysctlbyname("hw.machine", ...)` as per  [How to tell if your code is running on an iPhone or an iPhone3G?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688001/how-to-tell-if-your-code-is-running-on-an-iphone-or-an-iphone3g/688171#688171)

The returned result for 3GS should be "iPhone2,1"

Comment: Also, see http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/iphone-dev-determining-your-platform.ars (although you'll still have to add the 2,1 result for the 3GS).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so - nor even 1G phones from 3G. You have to use sysctls to get more detailed model info.

E.g. see [here](http://github.com/ars/uidevice-extension/blob/4dfdb4bf553dd0b0ea9bbd800b5df89218d75a04/UIDevice-hardware.m)

Answer (score 0):

maybe simpler solution - try

```
[[[UIDevice] currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported];
```

iPhone 3G has no multitasking, while 3GS and newer have.