# Proper method to detect device model (iPhone/iPod Touch)?

Tags: iphone, model, detection, ipod-touch

Is this the proper way to detect which device a user is running?

```
NSString *currentModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
if ([currentModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
    // The user is running on iPhone so allow Call, Camera, etc.
} else {
    // The user is running on a different device (iPod / iPad / iPhone Simulator) disallow Call.
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688001/how-to-tell-if-your-code-is-running-on-an-iphone-or-an-iphone3g

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a general solution but Apple in many cases provides API calls to check wether specific feature is supported or not. Examples could be:

- `+isSourceTypeAvailable:` and `+availableMediaTypesForSourceType:` in `UIImagePickerController` allowing you to check if camera is available for the current device.
- `+canSendMail` in `MFMailComposeViewController` to check if device is configured to send mail.
- `-canOpenURL` in `UIApplication` class to check if URL can be opened. For example it can be used to check if it is possible to make a phone call:

  ```
  if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
                                   [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]])
      //We cannot make a call - hide call button here
  ```

If such API calls are available for your purpose I would use them rather then rely on hardcoded string identifiers.

Comment: So how would that work for the Telephone? I use tel:// to dial a number together with an icon that shows that the number can be called. I don't want this icon to show if the user can not make a call directly. Which is the case on the iPad and iPod Touch.

Comment: Thank you very much Vladimir! I increased the answer number and marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd want to generalize that much (ie, there may eventually be an iPod with a camera, and I don't know that the iPhone will ALWAYS be called "iPhone"), but yes, this is the accepted way.

Comment: Sounds more like a comment than an answer, doesn't it?

Comment: They asked if this was the way to determine what device the user is running. How is "yes" a comment?