# How do I determine whether the current device is an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

In my universal app I need to check if the current device is an iPad or iPhone. How can I do this programmatically? I plan to put the code in my viewDidLoad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper method to detect device model (iPhone/iPod Touch)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447539/proper-method-to-detect-device-model-iphone-ipod-touch)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to programmatically detect iPad/iPhone hardware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862140/best-way-to-programmatically-detect-ipad-iphone-hardware)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check if `UISplitViewController` class available on the platform, if so make sure it is iPad using Apple's macro (notice that `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` constant is available only on iOS 3.2 and up).

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UISplitViewController") != nil && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        //currentDeviceType = iPad;
    }
    else {
        //currentDeviceType = iPhone;
    }
```

Comment: It's barely relevant now iOS 3.x is effectively gone, but the  availability of constants like `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` is determined at compile time, not run time.  `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` will still work fine on iOS versions older than 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

[Proper method to detect device model (iPhone/iPod Touch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447539/proper-method-to-detect-device-model-iphone-ipod-touch)

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple function in all my apps:

```
#import "isPad.h"
BOOL isPad () {
    static BOOL isPad;
    static BOOL used = NO;  
    if (used)
        return isPad;
    used = YES;
    NSRange range = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad"];
    isPad = range.location != NSNotFound;
    return isPad;
}
```

Comment: This test also has a lot of potential to fail on future devices.

Comment: @Dondragmer, where do you see potential fail on future devices? Do you mean future when UIDevice class will be deprecated? Or model property will return something else or be deprecated as well? It will be strange future and I don't look ahead so deep.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this.. this will help you.   

 NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;


        if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"]||[deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]||[deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"]){
        }
```

Comment: This test has a lot of potential to fail on future devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // Statements
}

else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
   // Statements
}
```