# How do I distinguish iPad 1 from iPad 2 in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

My app needs to know where iPad's mic is, and the only way I know is to see if it's running on iPad, or on iPad 2, and act accordingly.

So - how do I check the device model?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer your question directly, but in general, if you want to test for the presence of a microphone, then test for the presence of a microphone. Indirection is not nice (you might not care, but if you check it's an iPad 2, what happens when iPad 3 comes out?). It's bad practice...

Comment: While this doesn't tell you the answer, have a read at this -> http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/

Comment: @Dave - thanks, but I don't want to test for the presence of microphone (iPad1 also has a mike), I need to test the *location* of microphone - iPad1 has a mike near headphones port, and iPad2 has a mike at the center.

Comment: Aahh, I see! My bad - glad I could help below anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do exactly this, you need:

```
if(![[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPad2"])
{
UIAlertView *alertView = [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
message:@"Microphone not present" 
delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
}
```

Taken from [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/)

But as I said above, it'd be better to test for the presence of a Microphone than for the exact model. What if someone is using an iPad 1 with an external microphone?

EDIT: [This is the correct method](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/iphone-dev-determining-your-platform.ars), apologies, Merlin.

Also covered [in this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688001/how-to-tell-if-your-code-is-running-on-an-iphone-or-an-iphone3g)

Dave

Comment: thanks :) As I mentioned in the comment - I need the *location*, not the availability of microphone. I know that this is not a good practice, but I don't think there is an Api that will tell me where microphone is located :)

Comment: Good to hear - apologies for misinterpreting the question!

Comment: ou. I just tested the code on the real device - iPad2 returns @"iPad", not @"iPad2" as a device model :(

Comment: Merlin - apologies... This is the correct method - http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/iphone-dev-determining-your-platform.ars

Comment: Yeah, the initial method especially wouldn't work since the iPad 1 has a microphone, too.

Answer (score 2):

This SO answer provides a detailed method for using the `sysctlbyname("hw.machine"...` system.

[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920)